# Unable to share a folder with VM. Folder within a partition of type NTFS. Ubuntu 23.10 as base OS, with a Windows virtual machine. Can you help?

Tags: server, partitioning, permissions, mount, virtualbox

I am currently working with an IBM Linux server in which I have installed Ubuntu, version 23.10.

In this Linux OS, I recently installed Virtual Box virtual machine, version 7.0. I am a bioinformatician, and I am performing a transcriptome analysis project. The server machine has two block devices - `sda` and `sdb` - as you see below.

All block devices:

[image: All block devices]

`/dev/sda2` has a total size of 820.2 GB and a free space of 725.4GB. `/dev/sdb2` has a total size of 835.4GB and an available free space of 232.4 GB. The machine has a total RAM of 248 GB. While installing the VirtualBox, I allocated the hardware resources as follows.

- RAM - allocated 220GB
- Virtual Drive - 1016 GB

Virtual Machine Hardware allocation:

[image: Virtual Machine Hardware allocation]

The reason why I allocated 220GB RAM for the guest Windows 10: I want to run software on Windows whose ceiling of RAM usage while on performance is 203 GB.

#### Problem

All the raw files and other project-associated files are in `/dev/sdb2`. I wanted to share this folder with my Windows virtual machine. I  set the *shared clipboard* to *bidirectional*, and *Drag and Drop* to *Bidirectional*. Going to the *Shared Folder Settings*, I provided the folder path (in the */dev/sdb2* partition) and set the *Auto Mount Point*, and *Make Permanent* ON. Also, choosing the `*Optical drives*`, I checked the *VBoxGuestAdditions.iso*.

I am still not able to see the folder that I have shared on the guest Windows machine.

I have checked the permissions of the folder that I have shared. You can see the results here. It shows that the User, group, and Others have permissions to read, write, and execute, but the ownership is with the root. I tried to change ownership by typing the following command:

```
sudo chown palmyra:palmyra -R folder_to_be_shared
```

but it did not change the permission. Upon examining and exploring a bit I learned that the partition, where the folder to be shared is located, is of NTFS file system.

[image: Filesystem for /dev/sdb2 is ntfs]

If I were to change the filesystem type, I needed to reformat the partition to ext4. I don't know if this is what keeps the said folder from being shared, so I am looking for insights and a solution to this problem, and your support can be a great push for me to resume my transcriptome project.